# Getting multiple tag values when use find method in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, xml

I am using .find method to get value of xml tag. In my xml if xmltag is repeat, it gives me value of all tag.
Example

```
<Response>
<Result>0</Result>
<Message>Tenant Information fetched for tenantID=1</Message>
<Data>
    <Tenants>
        <row>
            <TenantID>1</TenantID>
            <TenantTypeID>1</TenantTypeID>
            <CardCode>CLINSH0184</CardCode>
            <CustomerName>S. H. Pitkar Orthotools Pvt Ltd</CustomerName>
            <CustomerGroup>VAT Customer</CustomerGroup>
            <ServiceContract>69</ServiceContract>
            <SUserID>S0004493123</SUserID>
            <ContactPerson>Nupur Pitkar</ContactPerson>
            <Phone1>123</Phone1>
            <Phone2>456</Phone2>
            <Mobile>789</Mobile>
            <Email>abcd@inecom.com.sg</Email>
            <StartDate>2014-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
            <EndDate>2015-01-01T00:00:00</EndDate>
            <Active>1</Active>
            <B1Version>8.82</B1Version>
            <PatchLevel>12</PatchLevel>
            <SqlVersion>2008</SqlVersion>
            <ServiceURL>http://localhost:8932/CRMService.asmx</ServiceURL>
            <DataBaseName>WTS</DataBaseName>
            <ExpiredMessage>Subscription to this account is expired. Please contact System Administrator</ExpiredMessage>
            <ExpirationMessage>Subscription to this account will expire soon. Please contact System Administrator</ExpirationMessage>
            <WarningDays>3</WarningDays>
            <logo>CLINSH0184.jpg</logo>
            <LicenseDetails>
                <row>
                    <ItemCode>SaaS-CRM-Sales</ItemCode>
                    <ItemName>SaaS - CRM Module-Sales</ItemName>
                    <StartDate>2014-07-15T00:00:00</StartDate>
                    <EndDate>2014-08-15T00:00:00</EndDate>
                    <License>1</License>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <ItemCode>SaaS-CRM-Purchase</ItemCode>
                    <ItemName>SaaS - CRM Module-Purchase</ItemName>
                    <StartDate>2014-07-15T00:00:00</StartDate>
                    <EndDate>2014-08-15T00:00:00</EndDate>
                    <License>2</License>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <ItemCode>SaaS-CRM-Service</ItemCode>
                    <ItemName>SaaS - CRM Module-Service</ItemName>
                    <StartDate>2014-07-15T00:00:00</StartDate>
                    <EndDate>2014-08-15T00:00:00</EndDate>
                    <License>3</License>
                </row>
            </LicenseDetails>
        </row>
    </Tenants>
</Data>
```

In the mention xml, I use below code to get the value of xml tag.

```
var bindName='Response Data Tenants row StartDate';
$xmlNode = $xml.find(bindName);
if ($xmlNode != null) {
  var value = $xmlNode.text();
  //do some thing with code.
  //here I am geting all value of xml tag start with 'StartDate'
  //I am expecting value of only single node specified in bindName variable.
}
```

Can anybody help me in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for only the `StartDate` in the `row` nodes, you should use the direct child selector instead of the descendant selector. Your final query selector should be:

`var bindName='Response Data Tenants > row > StartDate';`

That will exclude the `StartDate` from the `LicenseDetails` sections.

Keep in mind that if you have multiple `Tenants` or multiple `row` sections inside a single `Tenant` you may still get more than one result and should iterate over it using `.each()`:

```
$xmlNode = $xml.find(bindName);
if ($xmlNode.length > 0) {
    $xmlNode.each(function(index, item) {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the row you want, now it matches startdate in every row.

Change

```
var bindName='Response Data Tenants row StartDate';
```

to

```
var bindName='Response Data Tenants row row:first StartDate';
```

to match the first row.

**Update**
Sorry, updated because I found the upper level row element too.